# How to tell which Alternate Mode a display is using on 2016 MacBook Pro

Tags: display, usb, hdmi, displayport

I have a 13" MacBook Pro 2016 (non-touchbar) which I've connected to a couple of HDMI displays.  I know that Macs support both HDMI and DisplayPort over USB-C Alternate Modes, and I'd like to know which.

One of my adapters ([Choetech](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01M02FLYO)) says it uses DisplayPort 1.2 so I'd like to confirm this.  The other ([Bqeel](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01M0W2LZL)) doesn't say so I'd like to know how to find out.  I've got a couple of others that I'd like to investigate too.

I tried looking in Graphics/Displays in System Information but in both cases it says "Connection Type:  DVI or HDMI" so I'm not really any the wiser.